# How should I use `gargle` to connect to the Google Forms API in R?

Tags: r, google-forms-api, gargle

I have been working in R to create a shiny app that uses `googledrive` and `googlesheets4`. Everything has been working great, I hooked up OAuth and everything. Now, I'm looking to help build in more automation to my app and this includes digging in to Google Forms and since I'm already using `gargle`-based code, I'd like to stick with it.

Eventually, I'd like to be able to update a couple of a form's questions tailored to the specific use and user of the app so that they don't have to do this themselves. However, I have not been successful in making any API calls.

I have been testing my code in an interactive environment (not in a shiny app) first to make sure things work. I started by following [the instructions from `gargle` on downloading the discovery document for an API](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/request-helper-functions.html#discovery-documents). I did have to make a couple slight modifications to their code but I did successfully get a discovery document.

I then use the following

```
library(googledrive)
library(gargle)

fid <- "form_id"

# my slightly modified function to remove googledrive specific pieces
my_request_generate <- function(endpoint = character(),
                             params = list(),
                             key = NULL,
                             token = drive_token()) {

  .endpoints <- readRDS("app/endpoints.RData") # my saved file with the endpoints for the API
  ept <- .endpoints[[endpoint]]
  if (is.null(ept)) {
    print("Could not find your endpoint!")
  }
  
  req <- gargle::request_develop(endpoint = ept, params = params)
  
  gar_req <- gargle::request_build(
    path = req$path,
    method = req$method,
    params = req$params,
    body = req$body,
    token = token
  )
  gar_req
}

# test the API with just downloading the data for a form
# plus I want to see the structure to better create a future batchUpdate request
form_data_req <- my_request_generate(
  "forms.forms.get",
  params = list(
    formId = fid
  )
)

form_data_raw <- request_make(form_data_req)
gargle::response_process(form_data_raw)
```

This unfortunately gives me a 404 error.

```
Error:
! Client error: (404) Not Found
✖ Expected content type application/json, not text/html.
ℹ See
  /var/folders/v9/w6xbcfv15tb191g6fft32j1h0000gn/T//Rtmp9p2m0o/gargle-unexpected-html-error-113803b594433.html
  for the html error content.
ℹ Or execute
  `browseURL("/var/folders/v9/w6xbcfv15tb191g6fft32j1h0000gn/T//Rtmp9p2m0o/gargle-unexpected-html-error-113803b594433.html")`
  to view it in your browser.
```

Which just states that the url could not be found. This occurs whether I make the form private or able to be edited by anyone who has the link.

Where did I go wrong? Does the `googledrive` package not have the Forms API enabled? At some point along the way something is clearly disconnected but I can't find out where.